# How to solve $x''=x'x$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am given the ODE $x''=\frac{2}{3}x'x$

with initial values $x(1)=1$ and $x'(1)=1/3$.

This is not of form $x''+px'+qx=0$. So I guess the ansatz $x=Ce^{\lambda t}$ is not the right idea...

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3957967/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72212/42969, or this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2538220/42969

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x'x = \dfrac{1}{2} \dfrac{d}{dx} (x^2) $

Therefore, you have

$ \dfrac{d}{dx}(x') = \dfrac{1}{3} \dfrac{d}{dx} (x^2) $

Integrating,

$ x' = \dfrac{1}{3} x^2 + C $ for some $C$

Now you can integrate by separation of variables.

Actually, from the initial conditions, one deduces that $C = 0 $

Hence

$ \dfrac{  3 dx }{x^2 } = dt $

Integrating,

$ -\dfrac{3}{x} = t + D $

So that

$ x = - \dfrac{3}{t + D} $

Finally, $x(1) = 1$ , so $D = -4$

$x(t) = - \dfrac{3}{t - 4 } $

Check:

$x' = \dfrac{3}{(t - 4)^2} $

$x'' = \dfrac{ - 6 }{(t - 4)^3 } $

$ x x' = - \dfrac{ 9 }{ (t - 4)^2 } $

So $x'' = \dfrac{2}{3} x x' $

And  $x(1) = 1$ and $x'(1) = \dfrac{1}{3} $